# How to call an arraylist method to another class?

Tags: java, sql, database, methods, arraylist

I have the following code which is in a class `customerModel`. How do I call this method from another class called `customerController`?

```
public ArrayList<Customer> search(Customer cust) {
    ArrayList<Customer> custs = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    Connection connection = GaritsConnectivity.connect();
    Tuple<ResultSet, Statement> trs = GaritsConnectivity.read("SELECT * FROM Customer     WHERE CustomerID=1", connection);
    ResultSet rs = trs.getFirst();
    try {
        //takes a customer, returns it with the correct ID set
        while (rs.next()) {
            custs.add(createFromRs(rs));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        GaritsConnectivity.manageException("Customer search failure", ex);
    }
    GaritsConnectivity.doneReading(connection, trs);
    return custs;
}
```

Within the `customerController` class I would like to create another method where I can call the search method from `CustomerModel`.

```
public class customerController....

public boolean search(){
//what goes in here im lost? how can i connect the above search from customerModel to      customerController?
}
```

Comment: **ASAP** is badd....

Comment: Create object of the class to which this method belongs and using that object call this method.

Comment: if you have tried for ages...why now you need is asap?

Comment: for someone who needed an answer asap your not very responsive to suggestions are you? no comments or upvotes on either answer or no best answer -.-

Answer (score 0):

make another class in the same package, declare an instance of the class

```
customerModel cM = new customerModel();
cM.search(Customer cust);
```

this might not be what your after and almost didnt answer on principal this is a bad question but still this may help you

FYI syntax here isnt perfect eg. your method returns something so you may want to make the method call a declaration of a list or something like the answer below (or maybe above who knows) my point is i dont want to give a full sample answer for this question just something that helps a bit

Answer (score 0):

In your `CustomerController` do this:-

```
CustomerModel model = new CustomerModel();
List<Customer> myList = model.search(customer);
```

Comment: I want to create it inside another method within the CustomerController i.e
' public class CustomerCOntroller....

public boolean search????